# PowerShell high CPU prompts for execution policy

Tags: powershell, executionpolicy

I'm running the PowerShell script below. When CPU is high (100%), it will prompt for the execution policy. But when CPU is low it runs normally.

My policy: (remotesigned/unrestricted)
Enviroment: Windows Server 2012 R2, PowerShell v5.1

Script:

```
$sourcefolder="D:\A743"
$datenow = Get-Date
$processdate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-3)

Get-ChildItem $sourcefolder -File | Where-Object {
    $_.LastWriteTime -le $processdate
} | Remove-Item -Force
```

The message when automation fails:

> Execution Policy Change The execution policy helps protect you from
>   scripts that you do not trust. Changing the execution policy might
>   expose you to the security risks described in the
>   about_Execution_Policies help topic. Do you want to change the
>   execution  policy?
>   [Y] Yes  [N] No  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"):

I tried to convert the ps1 to exe and run under high CPU. It can run without prompting for the execution policy.

Comment: Is there a group policy or some other management system present? High CPU might be caused by applying the policy - which changes executionpolicy too.

Comment: Hi vonPryz, u means group policy will cause this?
cause that is fresh windows. with default group policy only.
and the cause of CPU it my company tools. when i run that tool, it high CPU then cause the executionpolicy thing. when i stop the tool, it low CPU, then powershell script run normal. 
if group policy of windows cause this,do you have any idea, which key may cause this executionpolicy thing change?
thanks

Comment: What, exactly, is "my company tools"?

Comment: is service(jar program). we process something. but 1 thing.  yesterday i try again, no more such problem.  
but last 3 month i face this. 
Thanks